# Kate Indenting Randomly

Tags: indentation, auto-indent, kate

when coding, if I type something after indentation, it indents the code.

example:

```
x = true
if x:
    print('thing')
print('thing 2')
```

would just become

```
x = true
if x:
    print('thing')
    print('thing 2')
```

this is extremely annoying and I would like to know how to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

A Kate developer here: Kate has the concept of `Indenters`. You can find them in the menu `Tools` > `Indentation` and then choose some specific indenter. You can also choose `None` to have no indentation at all, if that is what you are looking for.